# Material-UI Badge Example: how to use children property

Tags: material-ui

I am not really sure how to use children property of badge component.

Example here: [badge example](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/badge)

The Docs say:

children: The badge will be added relativelty to this node.

Can anyone please give an example how to use this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code for the badge component, it places the child/children nodes before the badge content.

From [the src](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/Badge/Badge.js):

```
  <div {...other} style={prepareStyles(Object.assign({}, styles.root, style))}>
    {children}
    <span style={prepareStyles(Object.assign({}, styles.badge, badgeStyle))}>
      {badgeContent}
    </span>
  </div>
```

Example:

```
    <Badge
      badgeContent={'Hello'}
      children={'Something before the content.'}
    />
```

would render like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful :)

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer if it satisfies your question. Thanks!